# Passing multiple vars to ->setUrl(route('api.users')) Laravel Datatables

Tags: laravel

I am using https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable

I can get a single variable into my controller by doing this

```
->setUrl(route('api.users',4))
```

"4" is the variable I am passing, it is the $group_id
I need to send a second variable here and can not do it.

What is in my view

```
{{ Datatable::table()
->addColumn('id','name')       // these are the column headings to be shown
->setUrl(route('api.users',4))   // this is the route where data will be retrieved
->render() 

}}
```

and in my controller

```
 public function getDatatable($group_id,$user_id)
{
if ($user_id==2){
   return Datatable::query(DB::table("comments")->where('post_id', $group_id))
    ->showColumns('fields','url')
    ->setSearchWithAlias()
    ->searchColumns("url")
    ->make();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam, so what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Hello, I did work it out in a different way. But the question here was ->setUrl(route('api.users',4)) the "4" is a variable, how could I send another variable with that URL request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls) you can simply do

`$url = route('routeName', $params);`

Where `$params` can be a string or int or an array of strings and ints

In your case it would become something like this:

`->setUrl(route('api.users', array(4, 6)))`